# NetCore Project Dependencies error

Tags: .net-core

I added .NetCore console application to the solution. It is failing to load the dependencies as shown in the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlyQe.jpg

I have installed .NetCore SDK 2.1.4 and .NetCore Runtime 2.0.5. I'm using visual studio commnunity 2017.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is target framework in your csproj file - "netcoreapp2.0" ?

Comment: Yes, target framework is .net core 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to fix the issue by recreating the solution from the scratch. This solution was originally created in visual studio 2015 with target framework .net core 1.0 and to upgrade it to 2.0, I opened it in visual studio 2017.
The upgrade log had this error. The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=660751&projecttype=8BB2217D-0F2D-49D1-97BC-3654ED321F3B. I recreated the solution in visual studio 2017 and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Rebuild the solution from the menu Build>Rebuild Solution

Comment: Rebuild is giving this error: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.0.  Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Have you downloaded the .NET 2.0 SDK from [microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)  OR looked at the error/warning list to see what the issue actually is?  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(NU1701)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: I have downloaded the sdk from this link only. Error/warning list doesn't contain anything related to this error.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you used a newer .netcore version ... And it is more recomended to use latest versions of .net core snd visual studio .. knowing that VS Community version 2022 is free and that .NET 6 is opensource

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).